# Почему C# может определить тип переменной, но не может определить тип константы?

Tags: c#, .net

Когда я определяю переменную, одновременно присваивая ей значение, я могу указать класс, наследником которого является результат выражения, могу указать интерфейс, который имплементируется результатом выражени или другой тип, к которому можно неявно привести этот результат. И в этом случае компилятор позволит мне не ошибиться с результатом выражения.

Так же я могу не указывать тип переменной, а предоставить эту возможность компилятору, воспользовавшись ключевым словом var.

```
var a = 5; // int
var b = 5.0; // double
```

Но когда я определяю константу - компилятор заставляет меня прописать тип константы в явном виде.

```
const int c = 5;
const double d = 5.0;
```

С чем связана такая непоследовательность? Неужели тип константы определить сложнее, чем тип переменной?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eric Lippert, ведущий разработчик компилятора C# отвечал на этот вопрос:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2128581/1159507

Если вкратце то var предназначена для упрощения конструкция типа `Dictionary<string, List<decimal>> priceTable = new Dictionary<string, List<decimal>>();`

`var` от слова `variable` - переменная, В то же время ключевое слово `const` подчеркивает что что значение меняться не может, поэтому ограничение компилятора тот исключительно логическое, чтоб не было нонсенса типа `const var`.

Comment: Спасибо, прочитал ссылку. По ней Эрик Липперт отмечает, что const pi = 3.14; вполне нормальное, как он считает, выражение, но в планах реализации таких конструкций нет.

Comment: Как мне кажется первопричиной указанной проблемы является плохой выбор имени для ключевого слова, обозначающего что тип данной переменной будет выведен компилятором автоматически. Подозреваю, что какое-то влияние оказал синтаксис JavaScript (что может быть более привычно для тех кто знает JS, но неверно по смыслу). Мне лично больше понравилось auto из C++ по моему более точно отражает смысл и не приводит к казусам вроде "const var"

Answer (score 3):

Он может. Но, во первых, будет несколько сложнее указать, что нужна именно константа. Как это сделать?

`var const b = 5.0`

Выглядит коряво.

Можно, конечно, анализировать, имзеняется ли данная переменная и добавлять константность автоматом:

```
var b1 = 42;
// b1 нигде больше ни используется, поэтому b1 - это константа!

var b2 = 42;

// Где-то в блоке ниже! Ага, b2 - не константа! Это переменная!
b2 = 36;
```

Но насколько это хорошо, когда тип переменной и ее поведение зависит от места использования? Другими словами, сделать-то это дело можно, но вот будет ли в этом смысл уверенности нет!

К тому же, константы очень легко переносятся из локальных переменных метода в поля, и тут сразу же появляется другая проблема: а не добавить ли неявную типизацию в поля? А это открывает еще пару ящиков Пандорры с котами Шредингера ([туц](https://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2011/08/c.html), если интересно).

UPDATE: Почему компилятор C# не может вывести тип лямбда-выраженя? (выношу ответ из комментария).

Компилятор C# не может вывести тип лямбды:

```
var foo = () => 42;
```

Не из-за ограничений параметрическим полиморфизмом:) Лямбды могут быть преобразованы к `Func<T>` или к `Expression<Func<T>>` и компилятор C# не знает, какой тип треубется пользователю.

Вот пример успешного вывода типов:

```
var foo = (Func<int>)(() => 42);
```

UPDATE 2: Почему плохо `const b = 5.0`?
В комментариях был задан вопрос, а почему бы не использовать `const b = 5.0`?
Ничего плохого в этом нет, но можно представить ответ команды разработчиков C# на предложение добавить эту возможность.

Вывод типов для константных выражений будет однобоким, если он будет работать в методах, но не будет работать в полях. Это значит, что новая возможность должна быть валидна как минимум в следующих случаях:

```
class Foo
{
  const boo = -42;
  public Foo()
  {
    const foo = 42;
  }
}
```

Вполне логично. Но в этом случае, мы получаем еще одну непоследовательность: вывод типов для констант работает в любом контексте, а вывод типов для переменных - только в рамках метода. Контр аргрументом может служить то, что семантически `var` не имеет смысла в рамках полей, а значит никакой рассогласованности нет. Но, с другой стороны, появится много желающих получить полноценный вывод типов для полей.

Нет никаких проблем добавить вывод типов и для полей (некоторые размышления от Липперта [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/why-no-var-on-fields)), но, получается что маленькая возможность "добавить вывод типов для констант" разрастается в достаточно большую фичу, которая затрагивает слишком много других областей.

С другой стороны, сейчас легко можно залить свое предложение на гитхаб и посмотреть, как сами разработчики компилятора на него отреагируют.

Comment: Чем плоха конструкция?

    const b = 5.0

Comment: Ничем. Но теперь у нас появляется два способа объявления неявных переменных. Что тоже будет непоследовательным:)

Comment: Где в моём примере Вы увидели объявление переменных?

Comment: Ок. Речь идет о выводе типов. Перефразирую:
Но теперь у нас появится два синтаксиса для вывода типов разных конструкций, что тоже будет непоследовтаельным.

Comment: Я, не понял фразу про несколько синтаксисов вывода типов. Можно пару примеров, разных синтаксисов? Пока я вижу, что компилятор C# легко разбирается с выводом типов переменных, но не справляется с выводом типов констант. Лично мне этот факт кажется непоследовательным. Ну я могу ещё понять, почему он тип лямбды не может определить - параметрический полимформизм это несколько сложно. Но почему частный случай переменной (константа присваивается в момент объявления и не изменяется) - для него сложно? (я знаю, что константа "инлайнится" при компиляции)

Comment: В исходном вопросе есть такая фраза: "С чем связана такая непоследовательность? Неужели тип константы определить сложнее, чем тип переменной?"

var x = 42;
const Y = 42;

Это же разный синтаксис. В пермом случае используется ключевое слово var, а во втором случае - ничего.

В выводе типов для констант нет физической проблемы. Вопрос в хорошем решении, которое будет подходить всем. Если у Вас лично есть предложение, то проще всего залить это в качестве предлолжения на github, его рассмотрят и примут.

И как я написал выше, останется проблема с выводом типов для констант уровня типов.

Comment: .. продолжение...
А это открывает ряд новых вопросов. Вот и получается, что последовательное решение без добавления неявных типов во все конструкции (как в F#), все равно будет непоследовательным.

Comment: var x = 42; const Y = 42; - я вижу, что оно отличается как раз ключевым словом. В первом случае это переменная, во втором случае - это константа. В первом случае используется, действительно, var, во втором - используется не "ничего", а ключевое слово const. Ну и я предлагаю закончить - выше написали, что Эрик Липперт считает нормальным указанную мной конструкцию, просто реализовываться этот кейс в C# не будет. Because ну вы знаете, that's why.

Comment: Все верно, но как быть в вашем случае с константами уровня экземпляра? Должен быть там тоже вывод типов? Если нет - не последовательно! Если да, то там же должен быть вывод типов и полей. В противном случае будет непоследовательно! Вот и получается, что добавлять эту штуку не хотят, чтобы не открывать ящик Пандорры, о котором я упомянул в оригинальном ответе.